# Caulking for transom glass

Tags: caulking, glass

I am remodeling a transom on a bedroom door. Here is the opening:

[image]

I plan to put 1/4", brownish tempered glass inside from the POV of the camera, against a 1/2" door stop (can be seen on right and top but haven't yet installed on the bottom) and then put some skinny molding to seal with little nails.

But I thought I should also use a bead of caulk around the glass, between it and the opening to reduce the impact of reverberation. Which type of caulking product should I use?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use caulk. It's going to be difficult to get everything in place without inadvertent squeeze out and other minor catastrophes. Get some glazing tape or simply some double-sided high density foam tape in the appropriate size. Ideally it would be slightly narrower than your stops and set to the outside so that you don't see it once the glass is installed.

Run that down your stops, press the glass in place, and you're good to go. I would consider putting it on both sides of a glass actually. This will  reduce the chance of vibration noise even more and also reduce the chance that you'll crack your glass when installing your stops.